# C# Mysql Link Combobox with Database values in textboxes

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox, database-connection

I have a form that has a ComboBox that has to display names and the when the name is select is has to show the different values from my mysql database in different textboxes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Dark_Heresy
{
    public partial class Required_Attributes : Form
    {
        public Required_Attributes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cb_Talents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = Mypass;";
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM dark_heresy.talents WHERE TalentName='" + cb_Talents.Text + "' ;";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                    string description = myReader.GetString("Description");
                    string strength = myReader.GetInt32("R_Str").ToString();
                    string weaponskill = myReader.GetInt32("R_WS").ToString();
                    string ballisticskill = myReader.GetInt32("R_BS").ToString();
                    string fellowship = myReader.GetInt32("R_Fel").ToString();
                    string perception = myReader.GetInt32("R_Per").ToString();
                    string intelligence = myReader.GetInt32("R_Int").ToString();
                    string agility = myReader.GetInt32("R_Agi").ToString();
                    string willpower = myReader.GetInt32("R_WP").ToString();
                    string toughness = myReader.GetInt32("R_Tough").ToString();
                    string talentrequired = myReader.GetString("Talent_required");
                    string skillrequired = myReader.GetString("Skill_required");
                    string classrequired = myReader.GetString("Class_required");

                    TextDescription.Text = description;
                    TextStrengh.Text = strength;
                    TextWeaponskill.Text = weaponskill;
                    TextBallisticskill.Text = ballisticskill;
                    TextFellowship.Text = fellowship;
                    TextPerception.Text = perception;
                    TextIntelligence.Text = intelligence;
                    TextAgility.Text = agility;
                    TextWillpower.Text = willpower;
                    TextToughness.Text = toughness;
                    TextTalent.Text = talentrequired;
                    TextSkill.Text = skillrequired;
                    TextClass.Text = classrequired;



                }
            }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: \r\n" + ex);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

However when i open the form and press the ComboBox, nothing happens, and nothing is shown, no syntax error occurs, what is wrong with the code?

UPDATE even if i change the code to:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Dark_Heresy
{
    public partial class Talents : Form
    {
        public Talents()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cb_Talents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Test");
            //string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = Lorena89;";
            //string Query = "SELECT * FROM dark_heresy.talents WHERE TalentName='" + cb_Talents.Text + "' ;";
            //MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            //MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            //MySqlDataReader myReader;

            //try
            //{
            //    conDataBase.Open();
            //    myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            //    while (myReader.Read())
            //    {

            //        string description = myReader.GetString("Description");
            //        string strength = myReader.GetInt32("R_Str").ToString();
            //        string weaponskill = myReader.GetInt32("R_WS").ToString();
            //        string ballisticskill = myReader.GetInt32("R_BS").ToString();
            //        string fellowship = myReader.GetInt32("R_Fel").ToString();
            //        string perception = myReader.GetInt32("R_Per").ToString();
            //        string intelligence = myReader.GetInt32("R_Int").ToString();
            //        string agility = myReader.GetInt32("R_Agi").ToString();
            //        string willpower = myReader.GetInt32("R_WP").ToString();
            //        string toughness = myReader.GetInt32("R_Tough").ToString();
            //        string talentrequired = myReader.GetString("Talent_required");
            //        string skillrequired = myReader.GetString("Skill_required");
            //        string classrequired = myReader.GetString("Class_required");

            //        TextDescription.Text = description;
            //        TextStrengh.Text = strength;
            //        TextWeaponskill.Text = weaponskill;
            //        TextBallisticskill.Text = ballisticskill;
            //        TextFellowship.Text = fellowship;
            //        TextPerception.Text = perception;
            //        TextIntelligence.Text = intelligence;
            //        TextAgility.Text = agility;
            //        TextWillpower.Text = willpower;
            //        TextToughness.Text = toughness;
            //        TextTalent.Text = talentrequired;
            //        TextSkill.Text = skillrequired;
            //        TextClass.Text = classrequired;

            //    }
            //}

            //    catch (Exception ex)
            //    {
            //        MessageBox.Show("Error: \r\n" + ex);
            //    }

            }

        private void Talents_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        }
    }
```

Nothing happens, the combobox is never fired up, how can i make it work.

Comment: Did you debug your code line by line and see what happens?

Comment: yes and it gets the values from the different names, however nothing happens after that

Comment: Are you sure your `Query` returns data in your database manager?

Comment: @SonerGönül well the information is at dark_heresy.talents, when i run it in mysql workbench the table is shown, hmm could it be the loading of the name that is not done in the combobox, that is the problem?

Comment: @SonerGönül I still cant make any sense on why it does not show anything, i have now tried to make a static value to show and nothing happens. When i do the samme command in mysql workbench, it shows me the details. I have now tried set debugg in line 21:
 private void cb_Talents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){, and it never reaches to that point no debugg is runned

Answer (score 1):

I would set a static value that you know exists in the database inside the query and see if it returns anything. This will tell you if your query is incorrect.

```
 string Query = "SELECT * FROM dark_heresy.talents WHERE TalentName='This.Guy';";
```

As per your second question, you can create static global variables inside your Required_Attributes form like:

```
public static string username;
public static string password;
```

And on the closing event of your login page, set the variables' values like:

```
private void Authenticate_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Required_Attributes.username = username.text;
        Required_Attributes.password = password.text; 
    }
```

Your connection string would look like this:

```
string constring = "datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username =" + username + "; password = " + password + ";";
```

Comment: changed it and actually does not show anything. but when i run the same code in mysqlworkbench
SELECT * FROM dark_heresy.talents WHERE TalentName = 'Ambidextrous'; i get a result

Comment: I have an update, it seems that there is something wrong with the combox box, becuase i have changed the code to just simple:
        private void cb_Talents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
and nothing happens!

Comment: I would delete the event for the selected index changed. Then go to the design view and double click the combobox to autogenerate the event. Try the MessageBox.Show("Test")l again and see what it does. Make sure that you are actually clicking on something different in the combobox or the event will not fire off.

Comment: i have tried and still nothing happens, it simply wont generate it. i have added now an eventhandler after initialzedcomponent
cb_Talents.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cb_Talents_SelectedIndexChanged); yet nothing happens

Comment: If you build your code, does it contain errors? It doesn't make sense that visual studio is not autogenerating the method for you. In design view if your right click the control and hit properties, then click the lightning bolt icon in the properties window, does it list selectedindexchanged set to the method that you created?

Comment: I have actually made it work, by loading the names in the combobox with "loaded" when the form starts up. and in selectedindexchanged i have passed the code that i posted in the question.